# Questions about Arveson's proof on essentially normal operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

The question is about the following part of the paper "A Note on essentially Normal Operators" by Arveson.

[image]
[image]

First we start with the dilation theorem of Naimark which is
$\phi(f) = P\pi(f)|_{\mathcal{H}} = P\pi(f)P$. I think the second equality is the same as the restriction?

Then following the argument I have $\phi(fg)-\phi(f)\phi(g) = P\pi(fg)P - P\pi(f)P^2\pi(g)P = PSTP - PSP^2TP = PSTP - PSPTP$.

We take $S=T^{*}$ hence $PT^{*}TP - PT^{*}PTP$. Now since $P=P^{\perp}$ we can write $PT^{*}TP - PT^{*}P^{\perp}TP$. From here I am a bit stuck. The paper claims $PT^{*}P^{\perp}TP$ is compact and furthermore $P^{\perp}TP$ and $PTP^{\perp}$ are compact.

From here it is also a mystery to me how we can see from that that we can write down any operator in $\pi(C(X))$ a 2x2 block matrix and the rest of the proof?

I am kind of stuck here for quite a bit to understand the reasoning. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First we start with the dilation theorem of Naimark which is
> $\phi(f) = P\pi(f)|_{\mathcal{H}} = P\pi(f)P$. I think the second equality is the same as the restriction?

In spirit, yes. In reality, no. The functions $P\pi(f)|_{\mathcal{H}}$ and $ P\pi(f)P$ have different domains.

> Now since $P=P^{\perp}$

No, not at all. $P^\perp=I-P$. The equality $P=P^\perp$ is impossible. What happens is that you have $K=PT^*TP-PT^*PTP$ is compact. This you can write as
$$
K=PT^*P^\perp TP. 
$$
Next what Arveson uses is that $K=(P^\perp TP)^*P^\perp TP$, and that if $X^*X$ is compact, then so is $X$. There are probably several ways to see this. One is to notice that $X^*X=|X|^2$, and that the square root of a compact positive operator is compact; hence $|X|$ is compact and then $X$ is compact by the polar decomposition.

So now $P^\perp TP$ is compact for any $T\in \pi(C(X))$. In particular for $T^*$, so $PTP^\perp=(P^\perp T^*P)^*$ is compact. Then $PT-TP$ is compact.

As for the $2\times 2$ matrix, given any projection, like $P$, you can write $H=PH\oplus P^\perp H$, and any operator can be seen like a $2\times 2$ block matrix. Namely, you associate $T$ with
$$
\begin{bmatrix} PTP& PTP^\perp\\ P^\perp TP&P^\perp TP^\perp\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Such a decomposition behaves like the usual matrices, particularly in the sense that multiplication is "row times column". In this picture,
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad P^\perp=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
so it is trivial to check that
$$
PT-TP=\begin{bmatrix} 0&PTP^\perp\\ -P^\perp TP&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

As for $B$,  $N$ is normal and $C$ is compact. So $\def\abajo{\\[0.2cm]}$
\begin{align}
A^*A-AA^*\oplus B^*B-BB^*& = (N+C)^*(N+C)-(N+C)(N+C)^*\abajo
&=N^*N-NN^*+C\,(\text{stuff})+(\text{stuff})\,C\abajo
&=C\,(\text{stuff})+(\text{stuff})\,C,
\end{align}
which is compact. So
$$
B^*B-BB^*=P^\perp(A^*A-AA^*\oplus B^*B-BB^*)P^\perp
$$
is compact.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough answer. O I see. For some reason I confused the orthogonal with the transpose... I think in the last matrix there is a minus missing in the left lower term.

As for the matrices, is there some reference that talks about such decompositions? First time I see something like this hence I'm curious if there is more to it. I am also confused by why in $B=P^{\perp}N|_{\mathcal{H}}\perp$ the last term is an orthonognality symbol and why the matrix $N$ looks how it looks in the paper.

Comment: The minus I have just edited it in. As for the $\perp$, if you look at the context, what it says is $$B=P^\perp N|_{H^\perp}.$$ And as for block matrices, I don't have a reference; they are mentioned in every text in operator algebras, I guess, but it's just a matter of thinking about them a bit to get a feel of how they work.

Comment: I see, makes sense thank you!

Comment: Maybe last question, how does one see in the end that $B^{*}B - BB^{*}$ is compact? The paper states that it is obvious from $A \oplus B = N + C$ (C being compact), but I can't see how.

Comment: I have edited that into the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I am having a hard time to see the first equality in both equations you added. I think I am a bit confused with arithmetical signs - we have the normal sum and the direct sum (which is coordinate wise). The normal one is used apparently for adding the essentially normal operators and and the normal one is symbolically to represent the equvialence class the direct sum belongs to right?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that in a way that suits your mindset. In the decomposition in terms of $P$ that is used throughout the proof, $$ A\oplus B=\begin{bmatrix} A&0\\0& B\end{bmatrix},$$ while $N+C$ is just an algebraic sum that doesn't need to play nice with the above decomposition. $$ \ $$ Another way to say it is that in this context, $A=PA|_H$ and $B=P^\perp B|_{H^\perp}$.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Thank you!